# Is there a simple way to export the data from a meteor deployed app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is there a simple way to export the data from a meteor deployed app?

So, for example, if I had deployed an app named test.meteor.com...

How could I easily download the data that has been collected by that app - so that I could run it locally with data from the deployed app?

Comment: Access meteor DB directly.. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31639624/2837412

Answer (score 90):

To get the URL for your deployed site at meteor.com use the command (you may need to provide your site password if you password protected it):

```
meteor mongo --url YOURSITE.meteor.com
```

Which will return something like :

```
mongodb://client:PASSWORD@sky.member1.mongolayer.com:27017/YOURSITE_meteor_com
```

Which you can give to a program like `mongodump`

```
mongodump -u client -h sky.member1.mongolayer.com:27017 -d YOURSITE_meteor_com\
          -p PASSWORD
```

The password is only good for one minute. For usage:

```
$ meteor --help mongo
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, except I would add that the -d should be yoursite_meteor_com.

Comment: Thanks, I was really looking for this. Just as a side note, the hostname for my meteor project was skybreak.member1.mongolayer.com instead of sky.member1.mongolayer.com

Comment: Yes, important to note here that the \ on the end of the database name is meant to let you continue the command on the next line in your terminal. It is not a part of the database name and you will see an error if you write out your command all on one line.

Comment: Not working for me. After I enter `meteor mongo --url YOURSITE.meteor.com`, It asked me `username & password`. I try the username & password which I use to login to my account in meteor but no luck.

Answer (score 38):

And here's how to do the opposite: (uploading your local monogo db to meteor)

https://gist.github.com/IslamMagdy/5519514

```
# How to upload local db to meteor:

# -h = host, -d = database name, -o = dump folder name
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3002 -d meteor -o meteor

# get meteor db url, username, and password
meteor mongo --url myapp.meteor.com

# -h = host, -d = database name (app domain), -p = password, folder = the path to the dumped db
mongorestore -u client -h c0.meteor.m0.mongolayer.com:27017 -d myapp_meteor_com -p 'password' folder/
```

Comment: I'm getting the following errors any ideas 
ERROR: ERROR: root directory must be a dump of a single database
ERROR: when specifying a db name with --db

Comment: @almog, be sure your `mongorestore` folder points to where the `.bson` files are. For example, with `mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3002 -d meteor`, the path to the dumped db for `mongorestore` (executed from the same directory as the `mongodump`) is `dump/meteor/`

Answer (score 10):

Based on Kasper Souren's solution I created an updated script that works with current versions of Meteor and also works when you protect your remote Meteor app with a password.

Please create the following script `parse-mongo-url.coffee`:

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn
mongo = spawn 'meteor', ['mongo', '--url', 'YOURPROJECT.meteor.com'], stdio: [process.stdin, 'pipe', process.stderr]

mongo.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
    data = data.toString()
    m = data.match /mongodb:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@([^:]+):27017\/([^\/]+)/
    if m?
        process.stdout.write "-u #{m[1]} -p #{m[2]} -h #{m[3]} -d #{m[4]}"
    else
        if data == 'Password: '
            process.stderr.write data
```

Then execute it like this in a *nix shell:

```
mongodump `coffee parse-mongo-url.coffee`
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful. Fumbling around with the username and password inside of the one minute timebox where the credentials are valid to put together a correct mongodump or mongorestore command gets old very quickly.

Answer (score 6):

I have created a tool, `mmongo`, that wraps all the Mongo DB client shell commands for convenient use on a Meteor database.  If you use `npm` (Node Package Manager), you can install it with:

```
npm install -g mmongo
```

Otherwise, see [README](https://github.com/skagedal/mmongo).

To back up your Meteor database, you can now do:

```
mmongo test.meteor.com dump
```

To upload it to your local development meteor would be:

```
mmongo restore dump/test_meteor_com
```

And if you accidentally delete your production database:

```
mmongo test.meteor.com --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'   # whoops!
```

You can easily restore it:

```
mmongo test.meteor.com restore dump/test_meteor_com
```

If you'd rather export a collection (say `tasks`) to something readable:

```
mmongo test.meteor.com export -c tasks -o tasks.json
```

Then you can open up `tasks.json` in your text editor, do some changes and insert the changes with:

```
mmongo test.meteor.com import tasks.json -c tasks --upsert
```

[Github](https://github.com/skagedal/mmongo), [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmongo)

Comment: I just wanted to add that in order to avoid [“system.users: not authorized” error](http://docs.mlab.com/backups/) you can also do this: `mmongo test.meteor.com dump --excludeCollection=system.users`

Answer (score 5):

I suppose your data is in a mongodb database, so if that's the case, the question is more mongo-related than meteor. You may take a look at [mongoexport and mongoimport command line tools](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools).

Edit (for example):

`mongoexport -h flame.mongohq.com:12345 -u my_user -p my_pwd -d my_db -c my_coll`

You need to install mongodb on your computer to have this command line tool, and obviously you need your mongodb informations. In the above example, I connect to MongoHQ (flame.mongohq.com is the host, '12345' is the port of your mongo server), but I don't know which Mongo host is actually used by the meteor hosting. If you tried the Meteor examples (TODOs, Leaderboard, etc.) locally, chances are you already installed Mongo, since it uses a local server by default.

Comment: Not sure if I can run mongo command line on the meteor server. Does anyone know?

Comment: In fact, you run it  from your computer, but you specify the cloud-hosted mongo information (host, port, probably user & pwd). I'll try to give you an example in a few minutes.

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully this helps you. The command is pretty straightforward, I showed the most useful/common arguments, by default it outputs to stdout, you can redirect it to a file or specify it directly as an argument. mongoexport --help is well detailed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution in bash

```
#! /bin/bash
# inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353547/bash-string-extraction-manipulation

# http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/
set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -x

# stackoverflow.com/questions/7216358/date-command-on-os-x-doesnt-have-iso-8601-i-option
function nowString {
    date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
}

NOW=$(nowString)

# prod_url="mongodb://...:...@...:.../..."
prod_pattern="mongodb://([^:]+):([^@]+)@([^:]+):([^/]+)/(.*)"
prod_url=$(meteor mongo katapoolt --url | tr -d '\n')
[[ ${prod_url} =~ ${prod_pattern} ]]
PROD_USER="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
PROD_PASSWORD="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
PROD_HOST="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
PROD_PORT="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
PROD_DB="${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
PROD_DUMP_DIR=dumps/${NOW}
mkdir -p dumps

# local_url="mongodb://...:.../..."
local_pattern="mongodb://([^:]+):([^/]+)/(.*)"
local_url=$(meteor mongo --url | tr -d '\n')
[[ ${local_url} =~ ${local_pattern} ]]
LOCAL_HOST="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
LOCAL_PORT="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
LOCAL_DB="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

mongodump --host ${PROD_HOST} --port ${PROD_PORT} --username ${PROD_USER} --password ${PROD_PASSWORD} --db ${PROD_DB} --out ${PROD_DUMP_DIR}
mongorestore --port ${LOCAL_PORT} --host ${LOCAL_HOST} --db ${LOCAL_DB} ${PROD_DUMP_DIR}/${PROD_DB}
```

Comment: Would be killer if remote url was an argv of the bash script! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does not work under Git Shell, as it seems the libregex shipped with msysgit does not support the =~ operator.

Answer (score 2):

[meteor-backup](https://github.com/tgoorden/meteor-backup) is by far the easiest way to do this.

```
sudo npm install -g meteor-db-utils
meteor-backup [domain] [collection...]
```

As of March 2015 you still need to specify all collections you want to fetch though (until [this issue](https://github.com/tgoorden/meteor-backup/issues/1) is resolved).

---

*Stuff from the past below*

I'm doing

```
mongodump $(meteor mongo -U example.meteor.com | coffee url2args.cfee)
```

together with this little coffeescript, with a mangled extension in order not to confuse Meteor, `url2args.cfee`:

```
stdin = process.openStdin()
stdin.setEncoding 'utf8'
stdin.on 'data', (input) ->
  m = input.match /mongodb:\/\/(\w+):((\w+-)+\w+)@((\w+\.)+\w+):27017\/(\w+)/
  console.log "-u #{m[1]} -h #{m[4]} -p #{m[2]} -d #{m[6]}"
```

(it would be nicer if meteor mongo -U --mongodumpoptions would give these options, or if mongodump would accept the mongo:// URL)

Answer (score 2):

```
# How to upload local db to meteor:

# -h = host, -d = database name, -o = dump folder name
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3001 -d meteor -o meteor

# get meteor db url, username, and password
meteor mongo --url myapp.meteor.com

# -h = host, -d = database name (app domain), -p = password, folder = the path to the dumped db
mongorestore -u client -h http://production-db-a2.meteor.io:27017 -d myapp_meteor_com -p 'password' folder/
```

While uploading local db to remote db, having an assertion Exception

```
shubham@shubham-PC:$ mongorestore -u client -h http://production-db-a2.meteor.io:27017 -d myapp_meteor_com -p my_password local/
2015-04-22T16:37:38.504+0530 Assertion failure _setName.size() src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 219
2015-04-22T16:37:38.506+0530 0xdcc299 0xd6c7c8 0xd4bfd2 0x663468 0x65d82e 0x605f98 0x606442 0x7f5d102f8ec5 0x60af41 
 mongorestore(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x39) [0xdcc299]
 mongorestore(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x198) [0xd6c7c8]
 mongorestore(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x102) [0xd4bfd2]
 mongorestore(_ZN5mongo16ConnectionStringC2ENS0_14ConnectionTypeERKSsS3_+0x1c8) [0x663468]
 mongorestore(_ZN5mongo16ConnectionString5parseERKSsRSs+0x1ce) [0x65d82e]
 mongorestore(_ZN5mongo4Tool4mainEiPPcS2_+0x2c8) [0x605f98]
 mongorestore(main+0x42) [0x606442]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f5d102f8ec5]
 mongorestore() [0x60af41]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::AssertionException'
  what():  assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:219
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this simple Rakefile to copy the live db to local.

To restore the live db to my local machine I just do...

```
rake copy_live_db
```

Replace `myapp` with the name of your meteor.com - e.g `myapp.meteor.com`.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'

desc "Backup the live db to local ./dump folder"
task :backup_live_db do
  uri = `meteor mongo myapp --url`
  pass = uri.match(/client:([^@]+)@/)[1]
  puts "Using live db password: #{pass}"
  `mongodump -h meteor.m0.mongolayer.com:27017 -d myapp_meteor_com -u client -p #{pass}`
end


desc "Copy live database to local"
task :copy_live_db => :backup_live_db do
  server =  `meteor mongo --url`
  uri = URI.parse(server)
  `mongorestore --host #{uri.host} --port #{uri.port} --db meteor --drop dump/myapp_meteor_com/`
end

desc "Restore last backup"
task :restore do
  server =  `meteor mongo --url`
  uri = URI.parse(server)
  `mongorestore --host #{uri.host} --port #{uri.port} --db meteor --drop dump/myapp_meteor_com/`
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an existing **local** mongodb database on your `meteor deploy myAppName` site, you need to dump, then restore the mongodb.

Follow the instructions above to `mongodump` (remember the path) and then run the following to generate your '`mongorestore`' (replaces the second step and copy/pasting):

`CMD=meteor mongo -U myAppName.meteor.com | tail -1 | sed 's_mongodb://\([a-z0-9\-]*\):\([a-f0-9\-]*\)@\(.*\)/\(.*\)_mongorestore -u \1 -p \2 -h \3 -d \4_'`

then

```
$CMD /path/to/dump
```

From [Can mongorestore take a single url argument instead of separate arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883103/can-mongorestore-take-a-single-url-argument-instead-of-separate-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a remotely mounted file system via [sshfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) and then [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to synchronize the mongodb's folder itself or your entire Meteor folder I believe as well. This is like doing an incremental backup and potentially more efficient.
It's possible to use the same solution for sending changes of your code, etc. so why not get you database changes back at the same time too?! (killing 2 birds with 1 stone)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple bash script that lets you dump your database from meteor.com hosted sites.

```
#!/bin/bash

site="rankz.meteor.com"
name="$(meteor mongo --url $site)"
echo $name

IFS='@' read -a mongoString <<< "$name"

echo "HEAD: ${mongoString[0]}"
echo "TAIL: ${mongoString[1]}"

IFS=':' read -a pwd <<< "${mongoString[0]}"

echo "${pwd[1]}"
echo "${pwd[1]:2}"
echo "${pwd[2]}"


IFS='/' read -a site <<< "${mongoString[1]}"

echo "${site[0]}"
echo "${site[1]}"


mongodump -u ${pwd[1]:2} -h ${site[0]} -d ${site[1]}\
          -p ${pwd[2]}
```