# Bash string extraction / manipulation

Tags: regex, string, bash, math

I have a kind of complicated string, the form is

"xxxp+NUMyyy"

where xxx, NUM, and yyy are all variable length, and '+' can be a mathematical operator, such as '-', '*', '/', or '='.

I am trying to figure out the best way to get what mathematical operator and number the user has entered.

I tried using combination of things like this:

```
    echo `expr match "tcp+111" '\([+-=*/]\)'`
    echo `expr match "tcp+111" '\(\+\-=\*/\)'`
```

Nothing has worked thus far. I'm thinking the easiest way to do such a thing is by using regular expressions, but maybe I'm wrong? What is a good way to do this?

Thank You.

example input: "tcjp-100" "p+1" "p+1:debug" "cp=11:v". I did forget to mention, before the operator there will always be the letter 'p'. In addition, 'xxx' and 'yyy' do not have to be present, but can be

Comment: Indeed, regular expressions are the way to go

Comment: Could you provide some sample input?

Comment: Your `tcp+111` string doesn't match the format you described, `xxxp+NUMyyy` --- I presume the `p` is a mistake, but there is no corresponding `yyy` in your string...

Comment: example input: "tcjp-100" "p+1" "p+1:debug" "cp=11:v". I did forget to mention, before the operator there will always be the letter 'p'. In addition, 'xxx' and 'yyy' do not have to be present, but can be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Bash's regex matching feature.

```
string="xxxp+3456yyy"
pattern="[^*/+-]*([*/+-]*)([[:digit:]]+).*"    # the hyphen must come last (or first, but after ^) in the character sets

[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"    # operator
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"    # number
```