# How to persist mongodb when deploying with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I `meteor deploy` my app, it seems to create an entirely new mongodb instance. I'd like to be able to deploy with the current mongodb have locally.

Same goes the other way -- I'd like to be able to download the mongodb back to my localhost after it has been deployed.

For clarification, I'd really like to know the follow:

1) how to deploy with a fresh mongodb
2) how to deploy to an existing deployed app without overwriting the old mongodb
3) how to download/sync mongodb locally with the existing deployed app
4) how to make local backups of mongodb

Comment: See [documentation on meteor reset] (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorreset) for question 1 and 2.  The answer to 4 is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12447710/728291).

Comment: 3 and 4 were my real questions but I didn't think there was any harm in clarifying the others.

Comment: I don't get the down vote...

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a [mongo dump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) using [meteor mongo](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteormongo) to export your local database and deploy your app using [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) which should also allow you to automate the database import and deployment process.

"Meteor Up (mup for short) is a command line tool that allows you to deploy any meteor app into your own server."

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the mongodb service and start a mongod instance in a separate terminal, by just typing `mongod`. This will let you monitor what's happening on the mongodb instance that you just started.

Open another terminal and do `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/nameOfDBgoesHere`
This will create a new DB named "nameOfDBgoesHere" and it won't overwrite what you currently have, unless you name it with the same name.

After that just start meteor by typing `meteor` in your program's folder. In the mongod terminal that you opened you should see some connections opening.

By default mongodb creates it's DB files in `/data/db`. If you have another meteor app and follow the same steps in another terminal, while keeping the name of the DB you specified in the MONGO_URL you will just connect to it from that app - without overwriting anything.

As for the syncing with a deployed app and the local backups of mongo - it seems like something that the mongodb website covers, but maybe someone can chime in here. Not sure if there is a meteor specific, easy way of doing this.