# How to make a backup and restore in meteor.js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to create a backup and restore in Meteor.js, but I don't have any 
solution to create a backup and restore MongoDB  database with Meteor.js.
I need some Guide line to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Restore datatabase : mongorestore --port  --db  .
backup/dump : mongoimport/mo

Comment: I want to create a backup and restore from webpage not from cmd because after I built a complete Web App, I will need a page for create backup and restore.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the Mongo database for your local (or inner) mongodb of meteor, enter in cmd (in the folder of your project):

```
meteor mongo
```

checkout also :
[Is there a simple way to export the data from a meteor deployed app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024888/is-there-a-simple-way-to-export-the-data-from-a-meteor-deployed-app)

Comment: I want to create like a webpage that I can backup and restore MongoDB from meteor client.

Comment: you will have to execute a shell command that does mongorestore.
first try to do it manually in the cmd(shell) and then in meteor